# situations for "If ever there was a cause for celebration ... " (past tense)

Tags: tense

[From Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/ever)

> If **ever** there was a cause for celebration, this peace treaty was it.

I understand the meaning of it. I just can't make up a situation where the sentence fits.

If it were in present tense, I guess I could imagine that the heads of some countries are discussing in a conference, just after ending a war, which is really disaster to the world. Therefor, none of them want a celebration.

> If ever there is a cause for celebration, this peace treaty is it.

How about the original one (past tense)? Could someone help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation for which the original formulation is perfectly apt is a discussion of the history of the treaty. The sentence means to me that there was in fact a celebration, and the author is confirming that said celebration was entirely appropriate.

Comment: Thank you. How about my imaginary situation? Does it make sense?

Comment: Yes, but this sentence is better:  If ever there would be a cause for celebration, this peace treaty is it.  Instead of "would", one might use "could".  Both are better than "is", although all three ("is, would, could") are grammatically correct.